# Replace column headings and sort them left to right

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following headings and columns:

```
A   B   C   D
H1  H2  H3  H4
a2  b2  c2  d2
a3  b3  c3  d3
a4  b4  c4  d4
a5  b5  c5  d5
a6  b6  c6  d6
a7  b7  c7  d7
```

First I want to replace the headings by copy/pasting from another sheet:

It will be like the following after replacing **A1:A4**:

```
A      B    C       D
Table  ID   Order   Price
a2     b2   c2      d2
a3     b3   c3      d3
a4     b4   c4      d4
a5     b5   c5      d5
a6     b6   c6      d6
a7     b7   c7      d7
```

Now once this replacing is done, I will need to order the columns alphabetically from left to right (A to Z).
The result is:

```
A   B     C      D
ID  Order Price  Table
b2  c2    d2     a2
b3  c3    d3     a3
b4  c4    d4     a4
b5  c5    d5     a5
b6  c6    d6     a6
b7  c7    d7     a7
```

How to achieve this using a VBA code?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with the following code, supposing the data is in `Sheet1` and the new headings that are stored in the `Sheet2`:

```
Sub replace_sort_headings()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:D1").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:D").Sort Key1:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Orientation:=xlLeftToRight

End Sub
```